# MySQL Group concat line separator

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

In my SQL query, I am joining two tables creatives and campaign and then using group_concat.

Below is my SQL query:

```
SELECT group_concat(creatives.creative_id) AS creative_ids, 
campaigns.id,creatives.creative_id, creatives.parentId, sum(creatives.views), sum(creatives.clicks)
FROM campaigns INNER JOIN creatives ON campaigns.id= creatives.parentId group by campaigns.id;
```

which produces result as below. You can see the two creative ids separated by comma:
[image]

I want to separate the result for both creative_id as below:

[image]

I did some online research, but I didn't find any syntax for GROUP_CONCAT line separator. Is there any other solution for this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should solve your problem now that I understand it better. This `JOINs` creatives to a subquery which gives the total views and clicks for each campaign.

```
SELECT creatives.creative_id AS creative_ids, ctotals.id, creatives.parentId, ctotals.views, ctotals.clicks
FROM creatives
JOIN (SELECT campaigns.id, campaigns.parentID, SUM(creatives.views) as views, SUM(creatives.clicks) as clicks
FROM creatives JOIN campaigns ON campaigns.id = creatives.parentId 
GROUP BY campaigns.id) ctotals on ctotals.parentID = creatives.parentID
```

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried your query. In this case, sum(creatives.views) and sum(creatives.clicks) is not working. I am getting two separate records for creative IDs, but sum(addition) is not happening.

Comment: Hi Rose, you are right, this will now give SUMs that are grouped by creative_id and campaign id (the sum of the lines for any campaign_id will add to the total in your query). Why do you want both lines to have the total sum? Or perhaps, why do you want to split the creative_ids onto two lines?

Comment: I want to calculate total clicks and view at campaign level per child creatives

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT creatives.creative_id AS creative_ids, 
campaigns.id,creatives.creative_id, creatives.parentId, sum(creatives.views), sum(creatives.clicks)
FROM campaigns INNER JOIN creatives ON campaigns.id= creatives.parentId 
group by campaigns.id;
```